# Convert single-user Apache Derby database to one with users

Tags: java, authentication, networking, derby

I have an Apache Derby database that, until now, has always been locally accessed. It needs to be accessed by multiple computers now, so I feel it ought to have a username/password.

1. How do I take the existing database and retroactively add a user
2. How do I provide local/network authentication for that user?

I recall looking through their docs a few years ago, and it seem like there was a lot left to a developer to implement in these cases.

To clarify more, regarding point #1, [this page](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevcsecureDbOwner.html) says:

> Attention: There is currently no way of changing the database owner once the database is created. This means that if you plan to run with SQL authorization enabled, you should make sure to create the database as the user you want to be the owner.

I think this means that I will probably have to create a new database with a named user, and migrate all date from the original single-user database to the new one. Is this correct? Is there an easier way?

Also regarding question number two, [the manual says](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/devguide/cdevcsecure42374.html)

> Important: Derby's built-in authentication mechanism is suitable only for development and testing purposes. It is strongly recommended that production systems rely on an external directory service such as LDAP or a user-defined class for authentication.

Which, to me, says that the builtin authentication isn't worth using. There's no way we're going to go to an LDAP integration either, so is there something in-between these two that is worth using?

Comment: Maybe you should look through their current docs first?

Comment: I have skimmed them, and they don't really appear any different.

Comment: Is [this page](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/devguide/cdevcsecure42374.html) any use? Says you need to set the `derby.connection.requireAuthentication` property to true and define users as described [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/devguide/cdevcsecure37817.html) e.g. set `derby.authentication.provider=BUILTIN`

Comment: Every time I look at the title of this question I misread it as "Convert _useless_ Apache Derby database..." ;-)   Must be time for bed...

Comment: Ha! I changed the title, and I updated the question with more detail on my questions/concerns. Thanks for the feedback so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention you're going from a single-user environment to a multi-user environment, you're probably going to be setting up the Network Server, so you will have two levels of security to consider: database authentication, and network server authentication.

You probably want to start here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/cadminapps49914.html
and here:
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevcsecure42374.html