# Using LDAP for Apache Derby

Tags: java, derby

I'd be grateful to hear of any others who share my problem and, perhaps, have a solution.

I'm using Apache Derby database and it involves using LDAP for my database users.

When I use the 'ij' tool, everything is as it should be. Users can only use the database if both their names and passwords are known to LDAP.

However, when I use the same code in pure Java, users are accepted even though the wrong password is used. That is, names are checked with LDAP but passwords seem to be disregarded.

The Java programs compile and run so there seems to be no problem with the settings for PATH and CLASSPATH.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ron Wates.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because the defaultConnectionMode is fullAccess for everyone. You can set these properties at database level programatically after creating the database and connecting it to the first time. After connecting to the database for the first time You should set all other required properties ex `Derby.database.defaultConnectionMode=noAccess` `Derby.connection.requireAuthentication=true`
`Derby.database.user` , `derby.authentication.provider=LDAP`and other ldap properties.

These properties will take effect after restarting the db.

See the links provided here in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9518516/1282907

this is the one you are looking for
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/rdevcsecureclientexample.html